# Grub unable to find /boot/grub/stage1 file when I try to make a backup of linux on compact flash card

Tags: boot, grub2, backup, grub-legacy

I am trying to make a backup of a compact flash card on another compact flash card. I have used many tools like **dd, Win32DiskImager, Ghost backup recovery** etc. But when I boot from the backup card, it fails and opens up the grub screen. I have tried solving this issues using root, setup and boot commands. But when I try to find **/boot/grub/stage1** or **/grub/stage1** file, it fails. Can someone help me with it?

Answer (score 0):

So, you wan't to rescue the Grub on your backup system I think, have you tried the Boot-repair-disk? Is a lubuntu based distro that have a utility to repair/install grub in your linux partition/hdd, is very effective, you just need to download and burn in a Pendrive, next you have to boot your live USB and then just follow the instructions, you will need internet connection too for download and install the respective grub packages for your system.

This is the download page: https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/

Answer (score 0):

When you say the backup card "fails and opens up the grub screen", what *exactly* do you see?

If you get a GRUB command prompt, then both `stage1` and `stage2` were in fact successfully loaded, and the problem might be in loading the GRUB configuration file, usually named `/boot/grub/menu.lst`.

In that case, you can use the `root` command to select the partition that contains the `/boot` directory, and then use the `configfile /boot/grub/menu.lst` or `configfile /grub/menu.lst` command to read it, depending on whether you have the `/boot` directory on your Linux root partition or as a separate partition. If successful, the GRUB boot menu should appear.

Note that although GRUB Legacy does not have a `ls` command, you may be able to use the TAB completion to see which disks and partitions you have available for the `root` command, and again to complete the filename for the `configfile` command: if the autocompletion works, you know your previous `root` command was correct. You can also use the `find /boot/grub/menu.lst` or `find /grub/menu.lst` to look for the configuration file on all partitions whose filesystems GRUB can read.

Also, note that although GRUB has a `root` command, it does not mean the *Linux* root filesystem: for GRUB, the Linux `root=` kernel parameter is just another meaningless string it just passes on to the kernel. The `root` command of GRUB refers to the *GRUB root directory*, which is normally `/boot` when your system is up and running.